# Create a function to pass html control "ui" as paramater.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-lists

I have there 6 UL and inside each UL i dynamically generate li from serverside. right now for 6 UL i am doing ti 6 times repetadly. Is there a way i can create a funciton to pass ul as an parameter in the function and call same function with different ul elements.

right now i have this

```
<ul ID="ul_1"></ul>
<ul ID="ul_2"></ul>  
<ul id="ul_3"></ul>
<ul id="ul_4"></ul>
```

server side code to populat is like this

```
foreach (String li in ListA)
{
    HtmlGenericControl uli = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    uli.InnerHtml = li;
    ul_1.Controls.Add(uli);
}
```

I am using this code for each of the UL that is 4 times but i am trying to create a function so that i can use the same function just passing the UL id. I am not having any idea...Any help folks....

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you want maybe you could try something like this.

**Model:**

```
public class ListItem {
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class ListOfItems {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public IList<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**View (for example using razor):**

```
@model IEnumerable<ListOfItems>
....
@foreach (var itemList in Model)
{ 
   <ul id="ul_@itemList.Id">
      @foreach(var item in itemList.Items) {
         <li>@item.Content</li>
      }
   </ul>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ViewList(){
   var model = new List<ListOfItems>();
   var listItem1 = new ListItem
   {
       Content = "My first list item!"
   };
   var listItem2 = new ListItem
   {
       Content = "My second list item!"
   };

   var listOfItems1 = new ListOfItems
   {
       Id = 1
   };

   listOfItems1.Item.Add(listItem1);
   listOfItems1.Item.Add(listItem2);

   model.Add(listOfItems1);
   return View(model);
}
```

A little bit of refactoring and you're good to go :)